# Does LTE-M1 work when RSRP is below thermal noise?

Tags: iot, cellular-network, lte, m2m, 4g

With my understanding of LTE-M1, it features coverage enhancement mode A and B, which is the main reason that LTE-M1 has deeper coverage, or allows higher MCL (maximum coupling loss).

I did some real world tests with SIM7080G and found out this is not the case. When RSRP is around -120dbm, the module detects there is network avaialble but cannot connect to it. I understand that the thermal noise floor for 180kHz (1x LTE RB) is -121.3dbm, but shouldn't the coverage enhancement mode overcome this by repetition?

Or I understand this wrong, repetition cannot recover signals below or near thermal noise, then how does LTE-M provides its claimed coverage enhancement of 10-15db over LTE cat0/1 devices?

Any advice is appreciated.